# Cartesian product data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have three or more independent variables represented as R vectors, like so:

```
A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- factor(c('x','y'))
C <- c(0.1,0.5)
```

and I want to take the Cartesian product of all of them and put the result into a data frame, like this:

```
A B C
1 x 0.1
1 x 0.5
1 y 0.1
1 y 0.5
2 x 0.1
2 x 0.5
2 y 0.1
2 y 0.5
3 x 0.1
3 x 0.5
3 y 0.1
3 y 0.5
```

I can do this by manually writing out calls to `rep`:

```
d <- data.frame(A = rep(A, times=length(B)*length(C)),
                B = rep(B, times=length(A), each=length(C)),
                C = rep(C, each=length(A)*length(B))
```

but there must be a more elegant way to do it, yes?  `product` in `itertools` does part of the job, but I can't find any way to absorb the output of an iterator and put it into a data frame.  Any suggestions?

p.s. The next step in this calculation looks like

```
d$D <- f(d$A, d$B, d$C)
```

so if you know a way to do both steps at once, that would also be helpful.

Comment: it would be useful if you specify what the function f does.

Comment: `f` is a placeholder for one of several different hairy mathematical calculations, but for purposes of this question, I *think* the thing you need to know is that they all take N vectors of appropriate type and produce one vector; all inputs must be the same length, and the output is also that length.

Comment: I would recommend changing the title of this question... "data table" now means something different in R.

Comment: @random_forest_fanatic I changed it to "data frame".  If that's not what you meant please clarify.  (I don't know what you are talking about, but it was always a data *frame* that I meant and the title was indeed sloppy of me.)

Comment: @random_forest_fanatic Dunno if you're planning on systematically arguing for changing such titles, but I would recommend you don't. Tabular data is a concept folks have (from sql, excel or elsewhere) and they may well google for answers using that term, not knowing the minutiae of R packages. I think it's best that we let them do so and not rewrite questions for "correctness". Besides, the R thing is `data.table`, not `data table`.

Comment: @Frank The reason for my pickiness is because I found this question because I was searching for exactly what the title states: how to do a cartesian product with data.table's in R.  This question doesn't pertain to that topic, and so I suggested changing it to avoid future confusion/misdirection.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid(A, B, C)`

---

**EDIT:** an alternative to using `do.call` to achieve the second part, is the function `mdply` from the package `plyr`:

```r
library(plyr)

d = expand.grid(x = A, y = B, z = C)
d = mdply(d, f)
```

To illustrate its usage using a trivial function 'paste', you can try

```r
d = mdply(d, 'paste', sep = '+');
```

Comment: Aha! I knew there had to be a standard library routine that did this, but could not find what it was called.  I am going to leave the question open in case someone has an answer to part two, though.

Comment: if f is a custom function, then you could modify it to accept a data frame as an argument and let the function handle the splitting into component vectors

Comment: Was staring at the plyr documentation, but didn't catch that this was what `mdply` was for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

There's a function manipulating dataframe, which is helpful in this case.

It can produce various join(in SQL terminology), while Cartesian product is a special case.

You have to convert the varibles to data frames first, because it take data frame as parameters.

so something like this will do:

```
A.B=merge(data.frame(A=A), data.frame(B=B),by=NULL);
A.B.C=merge(A.B, data.frame(C=C),by=NULL);
```

The only thing to care about is that rows are not sorted as you depicted.
You may sort them manually as you wish.

```
merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),
      by.x = by, by.y = by, all = FALSE, all.x = all, all.y = all,
      sort = TRUE, suffixes = c(".x",".y"),
      incomparables = NULL, ...)
```

"If by or both by.x and by.y are of length 0 (a length zero vector or NULL), the result, r, is the Cartesian product of x and y"

see this url for detail: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/merge.html

Answer (score 16):

With library `tidyr` one can use `tidyr::crossing` (order will be as in OP):

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(A,B,C)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#        A B         C
#    <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
#  1     1 x       0.1
#  2     1 x       0.5
#  3     1 y       0.1
#  4     1 y       0.5
#  5     2 x       0.1
#  6     2 x       0.5
#  7     2 y       0.1
#  8     2 y       0.5
#  9     3 x       0.1
# 10     3 x       0.5
# 11     3 y       0.1
# 12     3 y       0.5
```

The next step would be to use `tidyverse` and especially the `purrr::pmap*` family:

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(A,B,C) %>% mutate(D = pmap_chr(.,paste,sep="_"))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
#        A B         C D      
#    <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <chr>  
#  1     1 x       0.1 1_1_0.1
#  2     1 x       0.5 1_1_0.5
#  3     1 y       0.1 1_2_0.1
#  4     1 y       0.5 1_2_0.5
#  5     2 x       0.1 2_1_0.1
#  6     2 x       0.5 2_1_0.5
#  7     2 y       0.1 2_2_0.1
#  8     2 y       0.5 2_2_0.5
#  9     3 x       0.1 3_1_0.1
# 10     3 x       0.5 3_1_0.5
# 11     3 y       0.1 3_2_0.1
# 12     3 y       0.5 3_2_0.5
```

Answer (score 8):

Consider using the wonderful data.table library for expressiveness and speed.  It handles many plyr use-cases (relational group by), along with transform, subset and relational join using a fairly simple uniform syntax.

```
library(data.table)
d <- CJ(x=A, y=B, z=C)  # Cross join
d[, w:=f(x,y,z)]  # Mutates the data.table
```

or in one line

```
d <- CJ(x=A, y=B, z=C)[, w:=f(x,y,z)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to do both, using Ramnath's suggestion of `expand.grid`:

```
f <- function(x,y,z) paste(x,y,z,sep="+")
d <- expand.grid(x=A, y=B, z=C)
d$D <- do.call(f, d)
```

Note that `do.call` works on `d` "as-is" because a `data.frame` is a `list`.  But `do.call` expects the column names of `d` to match the argument names of `f`.

Comment: @Zack: Thanks; I've updated my response.  It's not a one-liner, but evaluating `f` is still easier with `do.call` than typing in each argument.

Answer (score 1):

Using cross join in `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)

A <- data.frame(c1 = c(1,2,3))
B <- data.frame(c2 = factor(c('x','y')))
C <- data.frame(c3 = c(0.1,0.5))

result <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM (A CROSS JOIN B) CROSS JOIN C')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can never remember that standard function `expand.grid`. So here's another version.

```
crossproduct <- function(...,FUN='data.frame') {
  args <- list(...)
  n1 <- names(args)
  n2 <- sapply(match.call()[1+1:length(args)], as.character)
  nn <- if (is.null(n1)) n2 else ifelse(n1!='',n1,n2)
  dims <- sapply(args,length)
  dimtot <- prod(dims)
  reps <- rev(cumprod(c(1,rev(dims))))[-1]
  cols <- lapply(1:length(dims), function(j)
                 args[[j]][1+((1:dimtot-1) %/% reps[j]) %% dims[j]])
  names(cols) <- nn
  do.call(match.fun(FUN),cols)
}

A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- factor(c('x','y'))
C <- c(.1,.5)

crossproduct(A,B,C)

crossproduct(A,B,C, FUN=function(...) paste(...,sep='_'))
```