# Which function/algorithm for this merging and filling operation?

Tags: algorithm, r

I have written R code that merges two data frames based on first column and for missing data adds the value from above. Here is what is does:

Two input data frames:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
5 d
```

And

```
1 e
4 f
6 g
```

My code gives this output:

```
   1 a e
   2 b e
   3 c e
   4 c f
   5 d f
   6 d g
```

My code is however inefficient as it is not vectorized properly. Are there some R functions which I could use? Basically a function I am looking for is that fills in missing values / NA values and takes the value from previous element and puts it in place of NA.

I looked through reference book of R, but could not find anything.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309217/cartesian-product-data-table-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution making use of `zoo::na.locf`

```
library(zoo)

a <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,5), v=c("a","b","c", "d"))
b <- data.frame(id=c(1,4,6), v=c("e", "f", "g"))

n <- max(c(a$id, b$id))

an <- merge(data.frame(id=1:n), a, all.x=T)
bn <- merge(data.frame(id=1:n), b, all.x=T)

an$v <- na.locf(an$v)
bn$v <- na.locf(bn$v)


data.frame(an$id, an$v, bn$v)
      an.id an.v bn.v
1     1    a    e
2     2    b    e
3     3    c    e
4     4    c    f
5     5    d    f
6     6    d    g
```

Comment: You sould directly merge the 2 data.frame's with all=T and sort=F, and not create the full sequence of ids (because you could create unexisting ids).