# Cartesian product with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, cartesian-product

I'm trying to find the dplyr function for cartesian product. I've two simple data.frame with no common variable:

```
x <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"))
y <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3))
```

I would like to reproduce the result of

```
merge(x, y)

  x y
1 a 1
2 b 1
3 c 1
4 a 2
5 b 2
6 c 2
7 a 3
8 b 3
9 c 3
```

I've already looked for this (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right?rq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309217/cartesian-product-data-frame-in-r)) without finding anything useful.

Comment: `expand.grid(x$x,y$y)` or `CJ(x$x, y$y)` from data.table

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [crossing](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html) from the `tidyr` package:

```
x <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"))
y <- data.frame(y=c(1,2,3))

crossing(x, y)
```

Result:

```
   x y
 1 a 1
 2 a 2
 3 a 3
 4 b 1
 5 b 2
 6 b 3
 7 c 1
 8 c 2
 9 c 3
```

Answer (score 10):

When x and y are database `tbl`s (`tbl_dbi` / `tbl_sql`) you can now also do:

`full_join(x, y, by = character())`

Added to dplyr at the end of 2017, and also gets translated to a `CROSS JOIN` in the DB world.  Saves the nastiness of having to introduce the fake variables.

I'm seeing comments now (Nov2022) that this *does* also work on standard dataframes!  Great news!

Comment: I'm running with dplyr 0.7.6 and this gives the error `Error in full_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches) : 
  by must specify variables to join by` for the given example. Any ideas?

Comment: Same error as @Lyngbakr with dplyr 0.7.8. Did this ever appear in dplyr? Absent this, I use `crossing()`, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: @andyyy What was the underlying type when this error occur? I've seen odd and different behaviours especially on data.tables.

Comment: Works fine with dataframes.

Answer (score 6):

If we need a `tidyverse` output, we can use `expand` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
y %>% 
   expand(y, x= x$x) %>%
   select(x,y)
# A tibble: 9 × 2
#       x     y
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      a     1
#2      b     1
#3      c     1
#4      a     2
#5      b     2
#6      c     2
#7      a     3
#8      b     3
#9      c     3
```

Answer (score 5):

When faced with this problem, I tend to do something like this:

```
x <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"))
y <- data.frame(y=c(1,2,3))
x %>% mutate(temp=1) %>% 
inner_join(y %>% mutate(temp=1),by="temp") %>%
dplyr::select(-temp)
```

If x and y are multi-column data frames, but I want to do every combination of a row of x with a row of y, then this is neater than any expand.grid() option that I can come up with

Answer (score 4):

```
expand.grid(x=c("a","b","c"),y=c(1,2,3))
```

Edit: Consider also this following elegant solution from "[Y T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541036/y-t)" for n more complex data.frame :

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/21911221/5350791](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693599/alternative-to-expand-grid-for-data-frames)

in short:

```
expand.grid.df <- function(...) Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by=NULL), list(...))
expand.grid.df(df1, df2, df3)
```

Comment: There is also [expand_grid](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand_grid.html) in package tidyr.

Answer (score 4):

This is a continuation of dsz's comment. Idea came from: http://jarrettmeyer.com/2018/07/10/cross-join-dplyr.

```
tbl_1$fake <- 1
tbl_2$fake <- 1
my_cross_join <- full_join(tbl_1, tbl_2, by = "fake") %>%
                 select(-fake)
```

I tested this on four columns of data ranging in size from 4 to 640 obs, and it took about 1.08 seconds.

Comment: I like this one. It's nice and simple, but not very performant in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Using two answers above, using `full_join()` with `by = character()` seems to be faster:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

df <- data.frame(blah = 1:10)

microbenchmark(diamonds %>% crossing(df))
Unit: milliseconds
                      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 diamonds %>% crossing(df) 21.70086 22.63943 23.72622 23.01447 24.25333 30.3367   100
microbenchmark(diamonds %>% full_join(df, by = character()))
Unit: milliseconds
                                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 diamonds %>% full_join(df, by = character()) 9.814783 10.23155 10.76592 10.44343 11.18464 15.71868   100
```