# Create list from two vectors with every combo of each

Tags: r

Let's say I have two vectors (in the case below, they're `cycles` and `thedates`) that I want to combine every pair combination between them in a list.  The code below gives me the output `inlist` that I want but I don't think it's very efficient.  I was trying different things with `outer` but I couldn't make it work.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
cycles <- c(1,2,10*1:24)
thedates <- seq(ymd('2016-08-13',tz='GMT'), ymd('2019-08-13',tz='GMT'),by='day')

inputs <- matrix(nrow=length(thedates)*length(cycles),ncol=2)
inputs[,1]  <- rep(thedates,each=length(cycles))
inputs[,2] <- rep(cycles,length(thedates))
inlist <- lapply(1:nrow(inputs), function(x) c(inputs[x,1], inputs[x,2]))
```

Comment: What about the `crossing` function from the tidyr package? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228379/cartesian-product-with-dplyr-r

Comment: Consider also `expand.grid` from the tinyverse, `base`, package.

Comment: FYI - this would be considered a cross or cartesian join, if you're trying to google the join types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `data.table` as a package, you can use the `CJ()` cross join function:

```
CJ(cycles, thedates)
```

It would be a lot faster than `expand.grid`:

```
expand.grid(cycles, thedates)
```

I also think having a bunch of lists isn't helpful but you could split it as @Reeza provided to match your output.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, not sure if it's more efficient though.

```
z = split(crossing(cycles, thedates), seq(length(cycles) * length(thedates)))
```

You get a list of lists of each two. If you want a tibble or dataframe, remove the `split` portion of that code but since you're working with lists I assumed that's something you need.

Comment: what package is `crossing` in?

Comment: It's part of tidyverse, within tidyr, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3