# Combine 2 dataframes with function, like cartesian product or cross join

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, cartesian-product, cross-join

I want to combine two dataframes of different sizes with a binary function (namely `str_count()`), such that the rows of `df1` (containing regex) become columns of `df2` (containing the text data).

[image: Sample product table result]

```
library(dplyr)

# dummy data
df1 <- 
  tribble(
    ~regex_name, ~regex_data
    , "reg1", "(\\w+ )"
    , "reg2", "\\d+"
  )

df2 <- 
  tribble(
    ~metadata, ~text
    , "meta1", "text 1"
    , "meta2", "text2 3 4"
  )

# should result in something like
df1_2 <- 
  tribble(
    ~metadata, ~text,       ~reg1, ~reg2
    , "meta1", "text 1",    1,     2
    , "meta2", "text2 3 4", 0,     3
  )
```

### What I've tried so far

After searching online for a bit, I think there are a few possible approaches that I could take that involves some problems or perhaps some unnecessary intermediate steps.

1. a. Use a `full_join` ( join `by=` what tho?) 
   b. Followed by `tidyr::spread()`, (or `pivot_wider()`??)
2. Use `purrr::cross2()` (or `cross_dfr()`) (but it gives the wrong structure?) followed by (b1.b)
3. Use some combination of `purrr::map2()` and `mutate` (I've not been able to get this to work properly, and `map2` requires the dataframes to be of the same length)

The use of regex is just as an example (also what I'm working with). 
Also, although I'm using `tidyverse` libraries, any other elegant(simple?) solution that works is fine (I'm just prone to make mistakes if there are too many intermediate steps).

Comment: The sample data doesn't give the correct results for `str_detect`. But it's a sample so I guess that's ok?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630818/5798459) mentions using [`tidyr::crossing`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html#details). It preserves dataframes unlike `purrr::cross2`. This is probably as simple as it will get, but I'm wondering if it's possible in one step?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr) # for example function

crossing(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate(regex_data = text %>% str_count(regex_data)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = regex_name, values_from = regex_data) # as alternative to spread
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   metadata text       reg1  reg2
#>   <chr>    <chr>     <int> <int>
#> 1 meta1    text 1        1     1
#> 2 meta2    text2 3 4     2     3
```