# join each row to the whole second table in R dplyr

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge, tidyverse

I have two tables:

```
table 1:
|   | a  | b  |
|---|----|----|
| 1 | a1 | b1 |
| 2 | a2 | b2 |
```

and

```
table 2: 
|   | c  | d  |
|---|----|----|
| 1 | c1 | d1 |
| 2 | c2 | d2 |
```

I want to join them in a way that each row of table one bind column-wise with table two to get this result:

```
|   | a  | b  | c  | d  |
|---|----|----|----|----|
| 1 | a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| 2 | a1 | b1 | c2 | d2 |
| 3 | a2 | b2 | c1 | d1 |
| 4 | a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 |
```

I feel like this is a duplicated question, but I could not find right wordings and search terms to find the answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand: where does row 1 come from: ` a1 | d1 | c1 | d1`?

Comment: It was a typo @TimTeaFan it is fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand: `a1 | b1 | c1 | d1`. In table one there is no row with `a1 | b1`. Should it be created?

Comment: Also where does a2 and a3 come from? They are neither in table one nor two.

Comment: @TimTeaFan. They were typos. My original data is restricted so I have to make dummy ones.

Comment: @deschen it was a type and it is fixed now.

Comment: I think this post answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228379/cartesian-product-with-dplyr-r

Comment: yes it does @RonakShah. can you flag it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to join, we can use `tidyr::expand_grid`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

table1 <- tibble(a = c("a1", "a2"),
                 b = c("b1", "b2"))

table2 <- tibble(c = c("c1","c2"),
                 d = c("d1", "d2"))

expand_grid(table1, table2)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   a     b     c     d    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a1    b1    c1    d1   
#> 2 a1    b1    c2    d2   
#> 3 a2    b2    c1    d1   
#> 4 a2    b2    c2    d2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I found a crude answer:

```
table1$key <- 1
table2$key <- 1
result <- left_join(table1,table2, by="key") %>%
              select(-key)
```

Any better answers is much appreciated.