# create data table by cartesian product (type) of vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

My question has two parts.
First, lets say I have long vectors
like `years`, `cities`, and `temp` below, and
I want to create a data table that includes
combinations of all the three vectors. 
For simplicity I create a short example here,
by cheating and using `cbind`:

```
years <- rep(c(1950:1951), 2)
cities <- c(rep("LA", 2), rep("NYC", 2))
temp <- c(10, 20, NA, 40)
dat_tb <- cbind(years, cities, temp) %>% data.table()

dat_tb
  years cities temp
1:  1950     LA   10
2:  1951     LA   20
3:  1950    NYC <NA>
4:  1951    NYC   40
```

My question is that if the vectors are large,
I have to compute number of repetitions I had created above,
to enable me to use `cbind`.
How can I create a data table like `dat_tb` above
just using the vectors below, without using `cbind`

```
years = c(1950, 1951)
cities = c("LA", "NYC")
temp = (10, 20, NA, 40)
```

The second part of my question is that lets say I 
accidentally dropped the NA values like so

`dat_tb <- na.omit(dat_tb)`

Now, I do not know where the NA was,
so, I use the answer of the question in the first part,
to initiate a data table that looks like:

```
   years cities temp
1:  1950     LA 666
2:  1951     LA 666
3:  1950    NYC 666
4:  1951    NYC 666
```

How can I convert the 666's 
using the data tale I have, after dropping 
the NA's:

```
   years cities temp
1:  1950     LA   10
2:  1951     LA   20
3:  1951    NYC   40
```

to go back to the data table with missing value

```
   years cities temp
1:  1950     LA   10
2:  1951     LA   20
3:  1950    NYC  666
4:  1951    NYC   40
```

Comment: Do you mean Cartesian product? The example does not appear to be a Cartesian product.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309217/cartesian-product-data-frame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We an use `CJ`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(years, cities, temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can directly make a table with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

years <- rep(c(1950:1951), 2)
cities <- c(rep("LA", 2), rep("NYC", 2))
temp <- c(10, 20, NA, 40)

data.table(years, cities, temp)

   years cities temp
1:  1950     LA   10
2:  1951     LA   20
3:  1950    NYC   NA
4:  1951    NYC   40
```

It also works when you have unequal vector length. Shorter vectors are repeated until they equal the length of the longest one. This means that it's not an exact match because of how it repeats (see  NYC has the NA in the first example while LA does here):

```
years = c(1950, 1951)
cities = c("LA", "NYC")
temp = (10, 20, NA, 40)
data.table(years, cities, temp)

   years cities temp
1:  1950     LA   10
2:  1951    NYC   20
3:  1950     LA   NA
4:  1951    NYC   40
```

For your second question, I don't follow, but you determine missing rows with an anti-join.

```
dat_tb2 <- na.omit(copy(dat_tb))

dat_tb[!dat_tb2, on = .(years,cities)]

   years cities temp
1:  1950    NYC <NA>

union(dat_tb2, dat_tb[!dat_tb2, on = .(years,cities)])
   years cities temp
1:  1950     LA   10
2:  1951     LA   20
3:  1951    NYC   40
4:  1950    NYC <NA>
```

Of course, you lose the row order but then again you should be careful before randomly omitting data :)

Comment: I did not want to use "rep", when there are 10 vectors, each different length, it is hard, and why do I wanna do that? CJ was helpful. That was why I said for simplicity I am doing two vectors here. :)

Comment: @NoLie, my answer doesn't have ```rep``` in it and it also answers the second part of your question.  See second code chunk for non ```rep``` solution. ```cbind()``` is poor practice for this - it makes a matrix and coerces the data types to a single class.